# How to access Spring Boot`s build properties as normal Spring properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I would like to use the build properties in `/META-INF/build-info.properties` as normal Spring properties, so that I am able to use them in via `spring-property` in my Logback configuration `logback-spring.xml`.

I was already able to use them, but something changed...

- The properties file `/META-INF/build-info.properties` is there.
- I am able get the bean `BuildProperties` as bean with the correct values.
- The build properties are not registred in the application context as property sources?

Does someone knows, how to use the build properties like normal Spring properties in my `logback-spring.xml`?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <springProperty scope="context" name="application" source="build.name"/>
  <springProperty scope="context" name="version" source="build.version"/>
```

Comment: They aren't regular properties so they aren't loaded. You would need to explicitly add them as a property source either by an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` or an `@PropertySource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Spring Boot application, make sure that the build-info.properties file is being loaded as a property source. This can be done by adding the following entry to your application.properties

```
spring.config.name=application,build-info
spring.config.location=classpath:/,classpath:/META-INF/
```

Once the build properties are loaded as normal Spring properties, you can use them in your logback-spring.xml configuration file by referencing them using the ${propertyKey} syntax.

like example-:

```
<configuration>
   <property resource="META-INF/build-info.properties" />

   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <!-- Use the build property in the appender configuration -->
       <encoder pattern="${build.version} - %msg%n" />
   </appender>

   <root level="INFO">
       <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
   </root>
</configuration>
```

In this example, the ${build.version} property is accessed from the build-info.properties file and used within the  configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I just want to leave an answer for the records. Configuring `spring.config.location` and `spring.config.name` inside application.properties *can* not work. I mean... just think about it... anyway: the solution is to provide the extra files in `spring.config.import` like so:

```
spring.config.import=classpath:git.properties,classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties
```

Full description here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-files-importing